# Reference in table of contents without section number

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, article

How can I make the Reference visible in the table of contents without numbering it? I use the document class `article`.
So far I have been using `\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}`, but this numbers the Reference like a section.

I have also tried `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}`, but this doesn't seem to work in a article.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you mean the bibliography as an entry in the toc? The `Reference` is a little bit misleading

Comment: Try loading `tocbibind` without the `numbib` option, that is `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}`

Comment: I mean bibliography. I'm sorry, reference is indeed a bit misleading.

Comment: Loading the tocbibind without the numbib worked! Seems actually very obvious, but I never payed any attention to numbib. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

**Brute force method** with `\addcontentsline`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First}
\blindtext[14]
\nocite{Lam94}
\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Better way with `heading=bibintoc` method from `biblatex` (it's easier)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First}
\blindtext[14]
\nocite{Lam94}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

[image]